# Operation on integer available in regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

This question is a bit lengthy. I have one data frame with 2 columns 3rd column is output format given below:
Dataframe
 -

```
            reg  value       o/p
0     2 for $20     11     20/2
1     4 for $24     12     24/4
2     2 for $30     13     30/2
3  Get $10 Cash     14     14
4     3 for $30     21     30/3
```

First, I have to match [\d]+ for [$][\d]+ in reg column and then have to update the value column as 2nd integer of reg divide by the first integer of reg if no match keeps same value.

my code is :

```
df["value"]=df["reg"].map(lambda x: (int(re.findall("[\d]+",x)[1]))/int(re.findall("[\d]+",x)[0]) if(re.search(r"[\d]+ for [$][\d]+" , x)) else x)
```

The code output is correct for match cases only.

Comment: The dataframe is confusing. It can seen like 3 columns, could you correct it?

Comment: 3rd column is having output

Comment: Copy paste sample dataframe from console as is. Don't modify. @Amitgupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda function was returning the value from the `reg` column when no match was found, however using the `map` function you don't have access to the data on the `value` column where the number to be replaced is. From what I understand from the question this may solve your problem. Let me know if you think otherwise.

Dataframe used as input:

```
            reg  value        o/p
0     2 for $20     11       20/2
1     4 for $24     12       24/4
2     2 for $30     13       30/2
3  Get $10 Cash     14         14
4     3 for $30     21       30/3
```

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("dataframe.txt")

print(df)

for row in df["reg"].index:
    if re.search(r"[\d]+ for [$][\d]+", df["reg"][row]):
        fa = re.findall("[\d]+", df["reg"][row])
        df.loc[row,"value"] = int(fa[1]) // int(fa[0])

print(df)
```

Output dataframe **df**:

```
            reg  value        o/p
0     2 for $20     10       20/2
1     4 for $24      6       24/4
2     2 for $30     15       30/2
3  Get $10 Cash     14         14
4     3 for $30     10       30/3
```